# Displaying unrepeated random numbers in Android

Tags: android

I use the following program to print out 4 groups of unrepeated random numbers,
with each group consisting of 7 numbers rangng from 0 - 30. Printing
in Java proceeds as expected. However, when used in an android app,
only one line of 7 numbers is printed instead of 4 lines.

Can anyone tell me why the result of printing in Java differs
from that in Android. How to modify the code in Android to get result
same as in Java?

```
IN JAVA    
public static void main(String[] args) {    
final int requiredNum = 7;     
final int range= 30;     
final int inputGroupNum = 4; 

 Random random = new Random();
 enter code herefor (int i=1; i<=inputGroupNum; i++) {
 Set set = new HashSet<Integer>(requiredNum);
 while(set.size()< requiredNum) {
 while (set.add(random.nextInt(range)) != true);
}
assert set.size() == requiredNum;
String result ="";
result += set + "\n";
System.out.print(result);
    }
}

IN ADROID
calBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
 public void onClick (View view) {     
 final int requiredNum = 7;     
 final int range= 30;     
 final int inputGroupNum = 4;     

 Random random = new Random();
 for (int i=1; i<=inputGroupNum; i++) {
 Set set = new HashSet<Integer>(requiredNum);
 while(set.size()< requiredNum) {
while (set.add(random.nextInt(range)) != true);
}
assert set.size() == requiredNum;
String result ="";
result += set + "\n";
displayTxt.setText(result);    
 }         
}         
});        


Example of print-out in Java                     
[16, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11]                                      
[2, 18, 24, 9, 26, 27, 11]    
[17, 4, 6, 8, 25, 11, 13]    
[0, 1, 2, 21, 24, 9, 28]

Example of display in Android    
[8, 27, 18, 4, 20, 28, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :

```
calBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
 public void onClick (View view) {     
 String result ="";
 final int requiredNum = 7;     
 final int range= 30;     
 final int inputGroupNum = 4;     

 Random random = new Random();
 for (int i=1; i<=inputGroupNum; i++) {
 Set set = new HashSet<Integer>(requiredNum);
 while(set.size()< requiredNum) {
while (set.add(random.nextInt(range)) != true);
}
assert set.size() == requiredNum;
result += set + "\n";
displayTxt.setText(result);    
 }         
}         
});
```